# C++ - Should you delete allocated memory in the copy assignment operator of a class that uses raw pointers?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

I am still somewhat new at c++, and I am a little confused about this.

Say we have struct `struct_x` that uses raw pointers as attributes. Should the raw pointers then be deleted in the copy assignment operator, when they are already allocated? Or should you just assign the new pointee to the pointer?
(I am aware that it is advised to use smart/unique/shared pointers).

Code example:

```cpp
struct struct_x {
public:

    // Some attributes.
    char*       m_arr           nullptr;
    size_t*     m_len =         nullptr;
    size_t*     m_alloc_len =   nullptr;

    // Default constructor.
    struct_x() {
        m_len =         new size_t(0);
        m_alloc_len =   new size_t(0);
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    // Treat "struct_x" as a unique pointer for this example.
    struct_x(const struct_x& x) {

        // Assign.
        m_arr = new char[*x.m_alloc_len + 1];
        memcpy(m_arr, x.m_arr,*x.m_len);
        m_len = new size_t(*x.m_len);
        m_alloc_len = new size_t(*x.m_alloc_len);

    }

    // Copy assignment operator.
    void operator =(const struct_x& x) {

        //
        //
        // OVER HERE
        //
        // Should the pointers be deleted when they are already allocated?
        // Like:
        if (m_arr != nullptr) { delete[] m_arr; }
        if (m_len != nullptr) { delete m_len; }
        if (m_alloc_len != nullptr) { delete m_alloc_len; }
        // Or not?

        // Assign.
        ...
    }

}
```

Second question:

Do I need to delete the old `m_arr` after using `memmove`?

```cpp
// Resize.
void resize(const len_t& req_len) {
    using T = char; // only for this example.
    if (req_len > m_alloc_len) {
        if (m_alloc_len == 0) { m_alloc_len = req_len; }
        m_alloc_len *= 16;
        T* l_arr = new T [m_alloc_len + 1];
        memmove(l_arr, m_arr, m_len);
        // if (m_arr != nullptr && m_arr) { delete [] m_arr; } // Do i need to delete here, no right?
        m_arr = l_arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers at all? Why raw owning pointers to single `size_t`s like `m_len` and `m_alloc_len`? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Since `m_len` and `m_alloc_len`  also need to be pointers in case `struct_x` is a shared type instead of an unique type like in the example.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Any thoughts on the original question though?

Comment: @user34534857 Yes they should.

Comment: @user34534857 You're wrong about `m_len` and `m_alloc_len` though. They do not need to be pointers. But `m_arr` needs deleteing in your assignment operator.

Comment: @user34534857 It depends. If you've already allocated enough to receive the data from what you are copying from, you do not need to allocate anything again (and don't need to delete the old allocation). If `m_alloc_len >= x.m_len` then don't allocate a new buffer. Just use the one you have.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Okay so conclustion: only when `m_arr` needs to be resized I should delete `m_arr`. And therefore never delete single pointers like `m_len` when they are already allocated. Right? And why is this?

Comment: `m_len`  and `m_alloc_len` should not be pointers. Just make them `size_t`s

Comment: Okayokay but the principle.

Comment: Like should you delete single pointers, regardless if they should be single pointers in the first place.

Comment: So is that conclusion correct..?

Comment: @user34534857 Check [this out](https://godbolt.org/z/rjP5rrPjr). That's how I'd do it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great thanks! Though why should `m_len` and `m_alloc_len` not be pointers if the struct is shared? Because when we have multiple copies of the struct and you add an item to `m_arr` and increment `m_len` it will also edit the `m_len` values of all other linked structs. Otherwise the linked arrays will be updated, and the `m_len` of the linked structs are left behind. What am i seeing wrong?

Comment: It depends on what the class does with allocated memory and also how it tracks the amount allocated. If copy assignment involves increasing size of dynamically allocated memory beyond what is already-allocated, then resizing (and possibly copying old to new) may be necessary. If your class separately tracks *amount*  allocated (capacity) and what is in use (size), some reallocations might be avoided. If pointed-to object(s) can't be copied/moved, other considerations may arise. More generally, though, prefer using a standard container over manual memory management e.g. with `new`/`delete`.

Comment: "if the struct is shared" *This* struct is *not* shared. To make a shareable resource you need more than just pointers, and then you do not allocate or delete anything in the copy assignment operator. You just copy the pointers and increment the usage count.

Comment: I know. This is just a mini version of my actual `array_t` that can be either unique or shared.

Comment: @TedLyngmo BTW Is there any difference in returning `*this` like in your example instead of returning `void` like in mine, for the assignment operator?

Comment: @user34534857 Yes, returning `*this` would make it have the expected signature of a copy assignment operator. It then allows for chaining, like in `if( (a = foo()) == b )` where the assignment of what's returned from `foo()` to `a` returns a reference to `a` which can then be compared with `b`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Okay! Very good to know, lol. And I also have one question left about my `resize` function from my `array_t` class. I have updated the question with the function code and some explanation.. :)

Comment: @user34534857 Please do not add that to this already accepted question. Ask specific questions, one at a time, separately. - But, yes, you need to deallocate the first array. `if (m_arr != nullptr && m_arr)` is not needed though. It checks if it's a `nullptr` twice and you don't actually need to check it at all. just `delete[] m_arr;`. The `nullptr` check is built-in into `delete[]`.

Comment: Also, prefer to use `std::copy` / `std::move` when copying/moving from arrays. `memcpy` and `memmove` only works for fundamental types, like `int` etc., while the standard library functions will work for any copyable/movable types.

Comment: Copy construction is easier done like this: `struct_x(const struct_x& x) { *this = x; }`. No need to duplicate copying the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing a string-like class as an exercise, then `m_len` and `m_alloc_len` should not be pointers at all. Only `m_arr` should be a pointer. If you are not doing an exercise, you should be using `std::string` or perhaps `std::vector<char>`.

Having said that...

It is perfectly fine and necessary to `delete` owning raw pointers in assignment operators of resource-managing classes.

There is a caveat though. The assignment operator should be protected against self-assignment. If you do

```
my_object = my_object;
```

then without such protection your program will access deleted memory area. You want this:

```
void operator =(const struct_x& x) {
  if (this != &x) {
    // contents of your assignment operator
  }
}
```

`my_object = my_object` is an unlikely assignment to appear in a program, but such things can and do happen, especially if there is indirection involved. Say when doing `a[i] = a[j]`, it is perfectly reasonable to have `i == j`.

There are other (better) ways to protect against self-assignment. You will encounter them in due course. You probably need to learn about move semantics first.before

Comment: Allright thanks! Good tip about the protection check. Though I am somewhat confused if you should or should not delete the single pointers if they are already allocated? According to @TedLyngmo you should not delete single pointers, and only delete the array when it needs to be resized. Which is correct?

Comment: @user34534857 "you should not delete single pointers" I'm not sure that's what he is saying. You should not use single pointers to begin with. That's what I'm saying and that's what I believe he is saying.

Comment: You should always delete the pointed to memory before overwriting the pointer. What TedLyngmo is saying is that you should not allocate new memory when the old memory is already the right size: `if (old_size != new_size) { delete[] ptr; ptr = new char[new_size]; }`